# Is there any way to handle iphone in-app purchases through the replacement of the app with another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I recently started looking into how to add in-app purchases to iphone applications, and I came across the Store Kit method using product identifiers (see here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases).  However, without looking too far into it, the process looks longer and more tedious than I had hoped.

Is it possible to implement in-app purchases by simply copying the app's code into a new file, adding the additional content to that file, and then having the in-app purchase simply "switch out" the 2 versions?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the framework is of course allowing you to use everything like a black box. So the answer is a Yes. Let me guide you.

1. Copy and import the project sources but ignore InAppRageIAPHelper.m
2. In your own app delegate or controller, do

   @interface YourAppDelegate : IAPHelper {

then

```
- (id)init { 
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
         @"your product id",
    nil];

if ((self = [super initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers])) {                

}
return self;
```

}

Now you can request products with [self requestProducts]. Your products are loaded when you receive a notification in - (void)productsLoaded:(NSNotification *)notification .

Comment: That seems a bit better, but I was hoping to bypass the product system altogether.  I was thinking something along the lines of this: You upload 2 apps, app 1 and app 2.  App 1 is what the consumer downloads from the store for free.  App 2 is the in-app purchase, and app 2 is essentially app 1 with additional content.  When the consumer makes the in-app purchase, the app store completely replaces app 1 with app 2.  

Or are productidentifiers needed for stand-alone apps as well?  Sorry, I haven't actually tried to put anything on the store yet--I want to make sure my apps are completely done!

Comment: This is 100% impossible. You need to think of another strategy. Apple does not allow free in-app purchase on the store. This is forbidden.